# React-native-windows, ellipsizeMode and numberOfLines

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-windows

For a Text component, are props ellipsizeMode and numberOfLines supported in react-native-windows?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything when I add these props, if I add numberOfLines={3} and ellipsizeMode='head'. The text still ellipsis on the tail